# How to mount docker tmpfs with exec,rw flags?

Tags: docker, mount

What command line options can be used for enabling a `tmpfs` (temporary file system) inside a Docker container, that is `rw` (read/write) accessible and files on this fs (file system) are executable?

Example would be a shared memory `tmpfs` with 1GByte size, but standard flag is `noexec`

```
( shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1048576k) )
```

with:

```
docker -it --shm-size=1G alpine /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass mount parameters to the `--tmpfs` parameter, e.g. `--tmpfs /mytmp:exec` would allow execution of files.

```
$ docker run --rm -it --tmpfs /mytmp:exec ubuntu bash -c "mount | grep mytmp"
tmpfs on /mytmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

Comment: Thx@all     '\n'man docker-run     '\n'--rm true|false     '\n'Automatically remove the container when it exits. The default is false.     '\n'--rm flag can work together with -d, and auto-removal will be done on daemon side. Note that it's incompatible with any restart policy other than none.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if docker people bothered to document their own software.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need namespace isolation, then you can use host IPC namespace (`--ipc=host`):

```
$ docker run --rm -it --ipc=host alpine sh -c 'mount | grep shm'
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev)
```

vs

```
$ docker run --rm -it --shm-size=1G alpine sh -c 'mount | grep shm'
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1048576k)`
```

Comment: Thx@all     '\n'At this point, for shared memory, namespace isolation (with shared kernel usage) seems more appropriate. '\n'man docker-run     '\n'--ipc=""     '\n'Sets the IPC mode for the container. The following values are accepted:     '\n'(empty), private, sharable, container:name-or-ID, host     '\n'If not specified is(empty), daemon default is used, which can either be private or shareable, depending on the daemon version and configuration.